# how do I fire onload events for elements within component html in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

So this is a 2 in 1 question.

First, I am trying to fire a function when an element, within a components html, loads. I tried it numerous ways, like: `<div [onload]="myFunction()">` this however results in the function being called multiple times, 10 to be exact. My guess is this is not the way to go, but I am not familiar enough to get it working properly. Also I would like to send the element along as a parameter. For example doing `<div #myDiv (click)="myFunction(myDiv)">` does work, but obviously this isn't fired onload of said element. Whats the proper way here, or am I obligated to do a querySelector...

Next is a question involving the injection of the ElementRef within the component. Now, [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html) tell me that using the 'nativeElement' property is not quite the way to go. I don't really understand why. Having a reference to the element in your component is a good thing, is it not? Or am I overseeing a separation of concern thing? I am asking because if my first question is not an option, I would like to use this element reference to do a querySelection of my desired onload firing elements in the ngOnInit function of the OnInit class.

All information is welcome, seeing the angular2 docs are not quite complete. Thank you.

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit
{
    public categories: Category[];
    public items: Item[];

    constructor
    (
        public element: ElementRef,
        private _categoryService: CategoryService,
        private _itemService: ItemService,
        private _router: Router
    ){}

    public registerDropdown(element:HTMLElement): void
    {
        console.log(element);
    }

    private getCategories(): void
    {
        this._categoryService.getAll().then((categories:Category[])=> this.categories = categories);
    }

    private getItems(): void
    {
        this._itemService.getAll().then((items:Item[])=> this.items = items);
    }

    public ngOnInit(): any
    {
        this.getCategories();
        this.getItems();
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="home">

    <div id="search">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- div in question, the [ngModel] is a shot in the dark -->
            <div #myDiv class="dropdown category" [ngModel]="registerDropdown(myDiv)">
                <span class="placeholder">Selecteer categorieën</span>
                <div class="the-drop">
                    <ul class="ul">
                        <li *ngFor="#category of categories">
                            <input type="checkbox" />{{category.long}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Is your `div` a component in itself? or could it be? Also could you post the relevant component and template code

Comment: It is not, the div is simply inside the component. And yes, give me a sec.

Comment: Could the `div` be a component or would that be against your design somehow? What you are asking for *is* possible, but I'm trying to get a picture so I can recommend the *best* way.

Comment: the div could be a component, but i would like to avoid it.

Comment: @SnareChops I added the code snipped.

Comment: @Ken have you tried this? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Query-var.html

Comment: @Langley I have not, very usefull, but not quite what I was hoping...

Answer (score 9):

For loading events, check out [this article](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html) starting at rookie Mistake #2.

For general events, I found `EventEmitter` to be useful as a way for child components (custom markup tags) to tell the parent component about the child's events. In the child, create a custom event (a class variable decorated with `@Output()` ) which will `.emit()` whenever you determine, and can include parameters of your EventEmitter's specified `<data type>`. Then the parent can handle the custom event and access the parameters that you bundled within `$event`. I am using the Angular 2 quickstart files.

**Child** Script:

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  templateUrl: 'app/my-child.component.html'
})
export class MyChildComponent {
  @Output() childReadyEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit(){
    //do any lines of code to init the child
    console.log("this executes second");
    //then finally,
    this.childReadyEvent.emit("string from child");        
  }
}
```

**Parent** Markup:

```
<h3>I'm the parent</h3>
<my-child (childReadyEvent)="parentHandlingFcn($event)"></my-child>
```

**Parent** Script:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MyChildComponent} from './my-child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  templateUrl: 'app/my-parent.component.html',
  directives: [MyChildComponent]
})
export class MyParentComponent {

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("this executes first");
  }

  parentHandlingFcn(receivedParam: string) {
    console.log("this executes third, with " + receivedParam); //string from child
  }

}
```

*Note:* you could also try `EventEmitter<MyChildComponent>` with `.emit(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You can grab an instance of your `div` using `Query` and then in the `ngOnInit` trigger the `registerDropdown` method and pass in the `nativeElement` from the `QueryList<ElementRef>`

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
  public categories: Category[];
  public items: Item[];

  constructor
  (
    public element: ElementRef,
    private _categoryService: CategoryService,
    private _itemService: ItemService,
    private _router: Router,
    @Query('myDiv') private elList: QueryList<ElementRef>
  ){}

  public registerDropdown(element:HTMLElement): void
  {
    console.log(element);
  }

  ...

  public ngOnInit(): any
  {
    this.getCategories();
    this.getItems();
    this.registerDropdown(elList.first.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: This however uses the ElementRef, where I will have to use the 'nativeElement'. Is this desired?

Comment: The warning about ElementRef is referring to needing to run in a browser. This is not an issue unless you plan on doing server side rendering.

Comment: The register dropdown will later be called for multiple elements, meaning I will have to query for each element separately. Is it not possible to do the register in html?

Comment: there is no serverside rendering, only within browsers.

Comment: The `QueryList` returns a list of elements that match. You should be able to have multiple instances and then just call `registerDropdown` for each one. Angular can access the HTML but the HTML cannot access Angular due to angular not containing a global reference on `window`

Comment: should i declare each element as an equal variable (meaning: can I all call them #someVarName). would it still work, I dont want to query for each element separately.

Comment: downvoted for dependence on jQuery - I'm trying to find an Angular 2 way to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

On further reading, it seems that implementing a Spy is the best way to achieve this:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#spy