# How to resubscribe to an observable?

Tags: angular

I have a child component view in my angular2 appplication:

.ts

```
      ngAfterViewInit() {
         this.form1Observable = form1.myForm.valueChanges;
         this.form1Observable.subscribe(() => // some code);
      }
```

.html

```
   <select (change)="change($event) #select>
         <option value="0">New</option>
         <option value="1">Existing</option>
   </select>
        <div *ngIf="select.value == 0">
           <myForm1></myForm1>
       </div>
   <div *ngIf="select.value == 1">
          <myOtherForm></myOtherForm>
   </div>
```

If i change the select, i `loose` the subscription that i made on the `ngAfterViewInit` method, so i bind the `change` method in the select to subscribe again:

```
   change($event) {
      setTimeout(() => { 
         if($event.target.value == 0) {
         this.form1Observable.subscribe(() => // some code);
      }, 500)}
   //If not set this time out got an error sayng that form1 is undefined.
```

The problem is that when i execute this `change($event)` method, the subscription doesnt work. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I fire onload events for elements within component html in angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327447/how-do-i-fire-onload-events-for-elements-within-component-html-in-angular2) See the answer, you could have your child component implement AfterViewInit and then emit an event for your parent control to know it is ready, the parent control subscribes to this event and then subscribes to the observable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just setting up the `subscribe` directly on the `myForm.valueChanges` and having it store a variable on the component. Then you can execute code on the variable instead of resubscribing. Copying `valueChanges` into a new variable won't get the updates sent to `valueChanges`.

If you wanted to create a new Observable from the `valueChanges` Observable, you could wrap its output in a ReplaySubject or BehaviorSubject method:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.form1Observable = new ReplaySubject<any>();
     form1.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((thing) => this.form1Observable.next(thing));

     this.form1Observable.subscribe(() => // some code)
  }
```

This seems counter-intuitive however, I'm sure depending on your use of the observable output that there's a better way for you to do this.